# SImple way to prepare model in Blender for face motions and send it to DeepMotion for tracking

Tags: animation, faces, unity

I am completely new to facial emotions in Blender. I want to get the job done in the easiest way possible with the help of Deepmotion.

I want to prepare the face in Blender and then send the model to Deep Motion for tracking and have Deep Motion transfer the emotion from my real face to the 3D model face.

Once I get the animation this way, I plan to transfer it to Unity 3D for the video game I'm making. What preparation should I do to the 3D face in Blender before sending it to Deep Motion? And then, of course, this animation should be able to be implemented in Unity 3D.

Can you point me to some simple tutorial for this, some simple video with explanations?

The animation I will make will be very simple, only movement of the mouth and eyebrows.

Comment: Sorry, this site is about using Blender, not DeepMotion so you cannot expect everybody to know how DeepMotion works. If you need help preparing a Blender model for DeepMotion you should tell us what the requirements of the target software are and where you are stuck at trying to achieve them in Blender.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't know - I have not done it till the moment. It could be not DeepMotion, it could be something other. Deepmotion is just the first that I saw for this job - because it can easily transfer the motion of your real face to the 3D model. I see that in Blender there are also some tools - but I don't know from where to start. To say it simply - I want an easy way to prepare a 3D face with animation for the motions, and after that - this to work in Unity 3D. Some video tutorial? I could pass without Deepmotion for tracking, to make only mouth movement and eyebrows

Comment: Video tutorials would be the best option to learn character animation, since this is not a tutorial site and it is usually expected to ask about a specific issue you have working on something. Unfortunately someone else has a good recommendation, I'm afraid I don't.